# How to support multiple cascade paths ? Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following entities:

```c#
public class Price 
{
   public int? PricelistId { get; set; }
   public int? AgreementId { get; set; }
   public virtual Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }
   public virtual Agreement Agreement { get; set; }
}

public class Agreement
{
   public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; }
}

public class Pricelist
{
   public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; }
}
```

I want Prices to cascade delete if I remove either a Pricelist or an Agreement.

Is this possible ? My fluent looks like this:

```
builder.Entity<Price>(entity =>
   {
      entity.HasOne(c => c.Agreement).WithMany(c => c.Prices).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
      entity.HasOne(c => c.Pricelist).WithMany(c => c.Prices).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
   });
```

When I try to commit I get the following error:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Prices_Agreements_AgreementId' on table 'Prices' may cause
cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.**

Comment: In SQL Server, you can't. You'll need to handle the cascading another way if you have one  that can cause multiple paths or cycles.

Comment: Kim, you may want to look at the many-to-many feature of EF. It doesn't require you to explicitly define Price. Also some additional information could be helpful. Are you using the price table in some other capacity or is it just to pair up price lists with agreements, where agreements are associated with clients and price lists have a collection of item prices? Cascading can work, unlike what @Larnu said if you have your FKs set up correctly. Your OnDelete action is on the Price entity, but it should be on the Agreement and PriceList entity.